# Use Same Class as Controller for Many Tables

Tags: c#, azure, c#-4.0, azure-mobile-services, azure-table-storage

I am new to asp.net and azure mobile services.

Have some questions:

1)I have used the TodoItemController to query data from azure table storage
(just used their sample class as given below)
How do i modify it so that it acts as Generic Class for all Tables and not just for one table.for eg:if i had another Table called person apart from Todo
i want it to use the same class for both tables

2)Is the method Im suggesting a bad design pattern and if so why?

3)I also dint understand how this class gets called.
Saw somewhere that ../tables/Todo 
is mapped to this class.if thats the case.Where is the mapping done.?

4)Will ApiController achieve my purpose 1?if So an example please

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.OData;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service;
using TempService.DataObjects;
using TempService.Models;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Query;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TempService.Controllers
{
public class TodoItemController : TableController<TodoItem>
{

    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);

        // Create a new Azure Storage domain manager using the stored 
        // connection string and the name of the table exposed by the controller.
        string connectionStringName = "StorageConnectionString";
        var tableName = controllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName.ToLowerInvariant();
        DomainManager = new StorageDomainManager<TodoItem>(connectionStringName,
            tableName, Request, Services);
    }

    public Task<IEnumerable<TodoItem>> GetAllTodoItems(ODataQueryOptions options)
    {
        // Call QueryAsync, passing the supplied query options.
        return DomainManager.QueryAsync(options);
    }

    // GET tables/TodoItem/1777
    public SingleResult<TodoItem> GetTodoItem(string id)
    {
        return Lookup(id);
    }

    // PATCH tables/TodoItem/1456
    public Task<TodoItem> PatchTodoItem(string id, Delta<TodoItem> patch)
    {
        return UpdateAsync(id, patch);
    }

    // POST tables/TodoItem
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostTodoItem(TodoItem item)
    {
        TodoItem current = await InsertAsync(item);
        return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
    }

    // DELETE tables/TodoItem/1234
    public Task DeleteTodoItem(string id)
    {
        return DeleteAsync(id);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I will try to address your questions by point:

1. Yes and no. What you are trying to do is follow the Repository Pattern. So yes, you can make a BaseRepository that will do the bulk of the work with a generic data type. No, you will still have classes that inherit the base but specify the generic data type.
2. No this is not a bad design pattern.
3. So the TableController is a specialized ApiController for the data table. It is called via the route configuration that translates the URL "/tables/TodoItem/Id"
4. Again, the TableController is an ApiController. Not sure it will help, but there are a number of examples of the "Repository Pattern" for Azure Mobile Services. You can look here to get an idea:
   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/574357/Repository-Pattern-with-Windows-Azure-Mobile-Servi

Comment: what if i want to do same thing in android..... can you give me some link to start with

Comment: thanks for answering .im marking as accepted.but it would be great if you can provide android client example as requested above.also like would be the pros and cons of using this pattern vs using table controllers for each table

Comment: Look around for some commentaries on "Repository Pattern". It's a common design pattern that has a lot of value. You'll find a number of pros and cons, for example, if your BaseRepository class has a "FindById" method, you should only have one implementation that is inherited for all of your "FindById" methods. Otherwise, if you use you potentially have this repeated in all of your controllers.

Comment: As for the Android client...what exactly are you looking for? The TableController in the question runs in the Mobile App in Azure. It is exposed as a rest API for interacting with the data. Your Android access code doesn't change from what you normally use for Mobile Apps. You can review the Android mobile starter app (in Azure) for more details. Are you asking for an example of an Android Repository Pattern in Java?

Comment: Maybe start here for a discussion of repository pattern: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-repository-design-pattern--net-35804